# Bootstrap5, why is it that I can't get anything to line up properly?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

For example, if you look at this, vertically it's not lined up. The button "overflows" a little, but the input doesn't.

[image: Email and Password inputs with a button, where the button overflows.]

Why is that? I'm using Bootstrap 5.2.3.
I'll include the code just in case.

I'm sorry if the problem (and the solution) is obvious, but I've never done frontend before, I'm just here practicing and experimenting with bootstrap.

```html
    <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center" style="min-height: 100vh;">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <div class="w-25 shadow p-4 m-4">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"
                            placeholder="E-mail">
                        <label for="email">E-mail</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control"
                            placeholder="Password">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row gap-2">
                <input type="submit" value="asd" class="btn btn-primary col">
                <input type="submit" value="asd" class="btn btn-primary col">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your buttons are in a "row" without child "col", I think it's the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As input elements, try placing them in a `col` container (`row` must have `col` as first child element), so that they pick up `col` padding (gutter) and line up with siblings.

Also, add `d-flex` to make buttons stretch, and move `gap-2` to that container to add space between the buttons:

```html
     <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">
     
     
<div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center" style="min-height: 100vh;">
  <h2>Login</h2>
  <div class="w-25 shadow p-4 m-4">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
          <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="E-mail">
          <label for="email">E-mail</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
          <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
          <label for="password">Password</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col d-flex gap-2">
        <input type="submit" value="asd" class="btn btn-primary col">
        <input type="submit" value="asd" class="btn btn-primary col">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```